# Why can’t we use FPRAS for #DNF to estimate #CNF?

Tags: counting

Why cant we approximate the number of satisfying assignments of a CNF formula $g$ by first counting the solutions to $\neg g$ (which is in DNF) using the FPRAS for $\#DNF$ and then estimating the $\#g$ to be $2^{n}-\#(\neg g)$?

PS: I say why we cant, because I don't see this approach tried anywhere and seems too trivial to not have been thought of !

Comment: Try working out what the definition of "approximation" for #DNF ensures about the relationship between the estimate you get and the true value.

Answer (score 4):

The complement of an independent set is a vertex cover, and vice versa.

There is a very simply 2-approximation algorithm for vertex cover.

In contrast, it is NP-hard to approximate independent set better than $\Omega(n^{1-\epsilon})$, for any constant $\epsilon > 0$.

The problem is that if we take a 2-approximation for vertex cover and complement it, we don't necessarily get a 2-approximation for independent set. As an example, consider a matching on $2n$ vertices. The minimum vertex cover here is $n$, and this is also the maximum independent set. The set of all vertices is a 2-approximation for minimum vertex cover, but its complement, the empty set, is not a 2-approximation of maximum independent set.

Your problem is similar.